# Laravel 5.8 : How to change registered user to verify email before they can login

Tags: php, laravel

I use php artisan make:auth and laravel MustVerify to make member system work.

I want to change laravel register email verify system from

"Register ->Login -> 
Verify email" to "Register -> Verify email -> Login"

Default laravel verify system is :

1. After user hit register button.
2. User auto login to system
3. show verify page

What I want, is :

1. User hit register button.
2. User have to verify email before they can login to system

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way would be to add a field to the user called `active` or `verified`. In case the use did not verify their email they would not be allowed to login to the system (this can be easily achieved by overriding the login function with your own). This way the user can't access the system before he/she validates their email and that field is set to true. This also helps for later if you don't want to delete users and would rather deactivate them.

Answer (score 0):

In Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php, insert this code on top part

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
```

and override the **register** method in RegistersUsers trait by simply writing this code to your RegisterController.php

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    // $this->guard()->login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Notice the commented code. That's where users auto login after registration.

The answer was already provided in [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-55-disable-auto-login-after-registration)